# Is bootstrap 2.2 or 2.X compatible with IE11?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-11, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am using bootstrap 2.2.1 for my application, will it be compatible with IE 11?

Bootstrap images are not displaying in IE 11 need to add any additional plugin??

I am also using Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 64-Bit, please suggest thanks in advance

```
<b:NavLink href="#Home:" ui:field="home" icon="HOME" iconSize="LARGE" title="Home" addStyleNames="{style.home-icon-align}"></b:NavLink>
```

same code working in all browsers except OS:Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 64-Bit and browser: IE 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure, why not.
IE11 supports al the nice stuff inside of bootstrap.

Look at IE11 as the same level of support for bootstrap (2.x or 3) as the latest FireFox or Opera.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but bootstrap images are not displaying in IE 11 need to add any additional plugin??

Comment: I am also using Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 64-Bit, please suggest thanks in advance.

Comment: images are not based on bootstrap, please provide some code to show what the problem is.

Comment: <b:NavLink href="#Home:" ui:field="home" icon="HOME" iconSize="LARGE" title="Home" addStyleNames="{style.home-icon-align}"></b:NavLink >  same code working in all browsers except OS:Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 64-Bit and browser: IE 11.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 2.3.2 seems to support IE7+. Be careful when including jQuery as it needs to be a compatible version too (for example 1.10.0)

see http://www.jenkramer.org/116-uncategorised/34-fluent-2013-introduction-to-twitter-bootstrap-workshop